# return new ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, researchkit

this is a follow up question to this : [Assign ViewController to Class or vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082413/assign-viewcontroller-to-class-or-vice-versa)

So i have a ViewController called SwipeStepViewController, it subclasses from ORKActiveStepViewController. In the SwipeStep class i try to override the default ViewController with my custom `SwipeStepViewController`.

I tried to override the `+stepViewControllerClass`
 method and return my Custom Viewcontroller inside the SwipeStep class:
    import ResearchKit

```
class SwipeStep:ORKActiveStep{

    override func stepViewControllerClass(){
        return SwipeStepViewController.self
    }

}
```

but this does not work at all.
I use researchkit, but i guess it is a general swift question.

Comment: You're trying to return a value but your function has a return type of `Void`.

Comment: no, the return type is Class : see -> https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/ResearchKit/Common/ORKFormStep.m

Comment: the particualar line  is 43-45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with ResearchKit, but after taking a look at the [Objective-C code](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/ResearchKit/Common/ORKFormStep.m) I believe your method should be:

```
override class func stepViewControllerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return SwipeStepViewController.self
}
```

To explain why you're getting the errors:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.
>
> *and*
>
> 'SwipeStepViewController.Type' is not convertible to '()'

take a look at the **class** method (indicated by the `+`) you're supposedly overriding:

```
+ (Class)stepViewControllerClass {
    return [ORKFormStepViewController class];
}
```

Compare this with your method:

```
override func stepViewControllerClass(){
    return SwipeStepViewController.self
}
```

which is neither a class method, nor returns a class and it's clear where the errors are coming from.

Comment: Just a small note : i had to remove the "class" keyword in the first codeblock. I guess, because it's a protocol ?

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party, but I believe your function should be as follows:

```
class SwipeStep : ORKActiveStep {
    static func stepViewControllerClass() -> SwipeStepViewController.Type {
        return SwipeStepViewController.self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That function should return a Class.  Take a look at the section in the Swift reference on Metatype Types:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Your function should be

```
override func stepViewControllerClass(){
    return SwipeStepViewController.self
}
```

Comment: I get 2 errors : Method does not override any method from its superclass and 'SwipeStepViewController.Type' is not convertible to '()'

Comment: Have you imported ResearchKit.Private?